# How to trim and edit mkv video file with subtitle at the same time?

Tags: video-editing, mkv

I have video with mkv extension. This mkv file also inculdes subtitle. Subtitle can be enabled os disabled using the an option in any video player. I need to cut some scenes from the movie. For example let's say the movie length is 90 minutes. I need to cut the scene from minute 23 to 25 and the scene from minute 77 to 83. How can I do it? Cutting these scenes while keeping the subtitle synchronized. Is there any program that trim the video and the subtitle at the same time.